# Why ImageView is not showing images on higher API

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I am making 4 buttons with image buttons inside and text underline and I want to change ImageView image when button is pressed. I have been testing it on android 4.0.4 API14 and everything was fine. These images were working and no problem occurred but when I switch EMULATOR to newer API like 20+, images in imageview are shown but when I press, image is no more visible till I restart activity or press top back button. Can someone help me to make this?

**MainActivity java class-**

```
package com.example.vojtap.terminal;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Intent nastaveni;
    Intent start;
    Button btn_settings;
    Button btn_ende;
    Button btn_start;
    Button btn_book;
    ImageView iv_settings;
    ImageView iv_start;
    ImageView iv_book;
    ImageView iv_ende;
    boolean myBool;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        nastaveni = new Intent(MainActivity.this, settings.class);
        start = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Start.class);
        btn_settings = findViewById(R.id.button_settings);
        btn_ende = findViewById(R.id.button_ende);
        btn_start = findViewById(R.id.button_start);
        btn_book = findViewById(R.id.button_book);
        iv_settings = findViewById(R.id.iv_settings);
        iv_book = findViewById(R.id.iv_book);
        iv_ende = findViewById(R.id.iv_ende);
        iv_start = findViewById(R.id.iv_schema);
        btn_settings.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.i("IMAGE", "motion event: " + event.toString());
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                        iv_settings.setImageResource(R.mipmap.settings_pressed);
                        btn_settings.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPressedBG));
                        btn_settings.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTextPress));
                        return false;
                    }
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                        startActivity(nastaveni);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        btn_settings.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                        iv_settings.setImageResource(R.mipmap.settings);
                        btn_settings.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTextPrim));
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        btn_start.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.i("IMAGE", "motion event: " + event.toString());
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                        iv_start.setImageResource(R.mipmap.schema_pressed);
                        btn_start.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPressedBG));
                        btn_start.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTextPress));
                        return false;
                    }
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                        startActivity(start);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        btn_start.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                        iv_start.setImageResource(R.mipmap.schema);
                        btn_start.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTextPrim));
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        btn_book.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.i("IMAGE", "motion event: " + event.toString());
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                        iv_book.setImageResource(R.mipmap.book_pressed);
                        btn_book.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPressedBG));
                        btn_book.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTextPress));
                        return false;
                    }
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                        startActivity(start);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        btn_book.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                        iv_book.setImageResource(R.mipmap.book);
                        btn_book.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTextPrim));
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        btn_ende.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.i("IMAGE", "motion event: " + event.toString());
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                        iv_ende.setImageResource(R.mipmap.close_pressed);
                        btn_ende.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorClosePressedBG));
                        btn_ende.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorClosePressedText));
                        return false;
                    }
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                        finish();
                        System.exit(0);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        btn_ende.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorCloseOrange));
                        iv_ende.setImageResource(R.mipmap.close);
                        btn_ende.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorOrangeText));
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**XML-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#E3ECFC">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4.1"
            android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:stretchColumns="*">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button_start"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/button_pressed"
                        android:ellipsize="marquee"
                        android:paddingTop="105dp"
                        android:text="@string/start"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorTextPrim"
                        android:textSize="30sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_schema"
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:background="@mipmap/schema" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button_book"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"

                        android:background="@drawable/button_pressed"

                        android:paddingTop="105dp"
                        android:text="@string/app_book"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorTextPrim"
                        android:textSize="30sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_book"
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@mipmap/book" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button_settings"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"

                        android:ellipsize="marquee"

                        android:paddingTop="105dp"
                        android:text="Nastavení"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorTextPrim"
                        android:textSize="30sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_settings"
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@mipmap/settings" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button_ende"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"

                        android:background="@drawable/close_pressed"

                        android:paddingTop="105dp"
                        android:text="Ukončit"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorCloseOrange"
                        android:textSize="30sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_ende"
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@mipmap/close" />
                </RelativeLayout>


            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4.1"
            android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Newer APIs might be generating different MotionEvents inside your TouchListener. You should debug and check which actions are being passed there. Also, please don't use Thread.sleep inside the main thread. Post a delayed Runnable instead because Android can keep on doing its UI work.

Comment: MotionsEvents should be the same or not?
11-28 15:24:24.767 28263-28263/com.example.vojtap.terminal I/IMAGE: motion event: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0,

Comment: I had a similar problem a while ago where, in some devices, I'd get ACTION_CANCEL instead of ACTION_UP as the last action of an user tap. So, I thought that could be your problem too.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i ve tried to add ACTION_CANCEL or edit ACTION_UP to CANCEL but it didnt help. Do you have some other ideas?

Comment: Try using GestureDetector to detect the user's click. I believe you'd have to change the image in the onDown() callback and reset the image in the onSingleTapUp() callback. See how to use it here: https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html

Comment: Formatted question subject and body.